# AngularJS display complex Object

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

i have the following JSON:

```
{
   "_id": "543e95d78a1cec2a38ed53ec",
   "result": {
      "CAR009": [
         {
            "name": "BMW"
         },
         {
            "name": "MERCEDES"
         }
      ],
      "BUS007": [
         {
            "name": "RENAULT"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I don't know in advance "CAR009" and "BUS007" is just for the example.

**I want it to display in my HTML:**

CAR009 : BMW, MERCEDES

BUS008 :  RENAULT

*Controller:*

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/categories/api)
  .success(function (cars) {
       var categoArray = [];
       for (var key in cars.result) {
          var car = cars.result[key];
          for (var idx in car) {
             categoArray.push(car[idx].category_name);
          }
        }

        $scope.categories = categoArray;
    })
   .error(function (cars) {
      console.log(tags);
});
```

Then in my *HTML*: (but it is not exactly what I want)

```
<div ng-repeat="categorie in categories">
       <li>{{categorie}}
</div>
```

I store in an array but I need to store in an **Object**?

How I can do that to make it easier to diplay this with AngularJS?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: My question is: How can I display in my HTML CAR009 : BMW, MERCEDES

; BUS008 : RENAULT  I want to have them like Object to manipulate them.

Comment: what are you getting on category (categorie)? is the same as each element in result?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper it is the JSON that I show first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `categories` has this structure:

```
    {
      "CAR009": [
         {
            "name": "BMW"
         },
         {
            "name": "MERCEDES"
         }
      ],
      "BUS007": [
         {
            "name": "RENAULT"
         }
      ]
   }
```

You want to do it like this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="(key, cars) in categories">
       {{key}}: <span ng-repeat="car in cars">{{car.name}}{{!$last?', ':''}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sggct2bq/)

Also, you may want to change this part of your code:

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/categories/api')
  .success(function (cars) {
        $scope.categories = cars.result;
    })
   .error(function (cars) {
      console.log(tags);
});
```

Comment: in categories I will not have the key, no?

Comment: @Jose I don't understand this question, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I would like to manipulate like an Object to use it for other things.

Comment: @Jose the title of your question is: "AngularJS display complex Object" and I'm showing you how you can display that object in your view. Perhaps you need to re-formulate your original question.

Comment: @Jose I just updated my answer with a **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sggct2bq/)**